# sshfs/fuse set limit/max size for a mounted folder on the ssh server for the connected user with sshd_config?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, sshfs, fuse

How can i set a limit size for a mounted `sshfs/fuse` folder in `sshd_config`?

With this command i `sshfs/fuse` a folder from the server to a folder on my machine.

```
sshfs -o IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/[KEY] -p [XXXX] [USER]@[IP]:/serverfolder /clientfolder
```

Is it possible to limit the size of the folder on the server | `:/serverfolder`
as an example to `1GB` in `sshd_config` without this solution in this post?

[Restrict Directory Size | create a filesystem as a file and mount it](https://serverfault.com/questions/105040/restrict-directory-size)

Answer (score 3):

The SSH server does not have any control over the files or directories that are accessed via SSHFS/FUSE.
It is not possible to set a specific size limit or quota for a mounted folder on the SSH server using sshd_config.

Use a file system that supports this feature, such as ZFS or Btrfs to implement a file size or quota limit
You could use a tool such as quota or edquota to set a user-specific quota limit on the SSH server's file system.These methods may not be compatible with SSHFS/FUSE, so you need to test them before implementing them in a production environment.